# React Native Navigation usage in android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

For 
https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/

They given usage for ios not android

https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/usage

Need help!

Comment: modify it inside `index.android.js`. from my experience, they are almost the same.

Comment: @Val: But What to write?

Comment: exactly the same as example `index.ios.js`. try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The usage provided in the example is just for reference but it works for both Android and IOS.

If you are building a redux based application you should use https://reactnavigation.org/ for navigation according to the documentation for react native http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.46/docs/navigation.html#navigating-between-screens